# Two tables (One To Many) And table with many have (One To Zero Or One) with the table One

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, ef-code-first, data-annotations, code-first

**Two Tables One To Many**

1. VehicleStatus  {Id , LastVehicleStatusUpdateId}
2. VehicleStatusUpdated  {Id, VehicleStatusId, IsResponse }

**I need to make (one to zero or one) to last record in VehicleStatusUpdated ...**

LastVehicleStatusUpdateId ==> Navigator To VehicleStatus
like This
[image]

How can i make it with Entity Framework Annotation ??!!

```
public class Vehicle : IEntity<int>
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }
    public virtual VehicleStatus VehicleStatus { get; set; }
}
public class VehicleStatus : IEntity<int>
{
    [ForeignKey("Vehicle")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Vehicle Vehicle { get; set; }
    public int? LastVehicleStatusUpdateId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("LastVehicleStatusUpdateId")]
    public virtual VehicleStatusUpdate LastVehicleStatusUpdate { get; set; }
    public virtual List<VehicleStatusUpdate> VehicleStatusUpdates { get; set; 
}
public class VehicleStatusUpdate : IEntity<int>
{
     [ForeignKey("LastVehicleStatus")]
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public DateTime UpdatedTime { get; set; }
     public bool IsResponse { get; set; }
     public int VehicleStatusId { get; set; }
     [ForeignKey("VehicleStatusId")]
     public virtual VehicleStatus VehicleStatus { get; set; }
 }
```

I Tried this i got =>

> Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation property 'VehicleStatus.LastVehicleStatusUpdate' of type 'VehicleStatusUpdate'. Either manually configure the relationship, or ignore this property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.

[image]

Comment: I had a similar problem before.